# How can I see the files that need to be synced with Windows Live Mesh

Tags: windows-live-mesh

I an using Windows Live Mesh to syncronise files across two computers, I can see the number of files that still needs to be delivered but I cannot see which files are still in the queue.

Is there any way to see which files are waiting to be transfered in Windows Live Mesh?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the files that are in the queue if you open the live mesh interface from the computer that is waiting to receive the files. Open the live mesh interface and, next to the synced folder, after the **"Waiting to receive XYZ files"** there will be a link **"View Files"**. My version is 2011 Build 15.4.3555.0308